How to save PowerQuery source so that I can duplicate the spreadsheet and not have the source referring back to the original spreadsheet
Okay so I probably didn't explain very well in the long title so.....
I have an excel spreadsheet that uses power query. The source for the power query queries are within the workbook itself, so it basically references itself to grab the raw data from a table on one of its sheets.
I want to be able to duplicate this spreadsheet for different reasons and have saved a new copy, the problem is that the source in the new copy refers back to the original spreadsheet so now pulls in the wrong data.
I know that I can go into the queries and update the source, however is there a way to avoid having to do this?
Thanks in advance.

If you are referring to data in the same workbook, you should be using Excel.CurrentWorkbook() which would not have the problem you describe.

yeah but where should I be referring to this? When I create my power query it simply asks me what I would like to use and I select workbook.

You should be using the Data from Table/Range option, not from Excel Workbook.

You can create in a cell in a hidden sheet where you use the formula =CELL("filename",A1) to get the full path of the current workbook.
Load this cell into Power Query as a table :
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="MyTable]}[Content],
    Path = Text.BeforeDelimiter(FilePathFromCell, "]"),
    YourData = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(Path & "[SheetName]"), null, true)
in
    MyData


how would I load this into power query as you state? I am on excel for Mac as well not sure if that makes a difference. I currently have all of my tables and references setup, so it would be good to be able to add a simple update to make it work.

You didn't mention working on Mac in your original question. Now I am a little bit confused on what you want to achieve
